# opencart windows permissions

Tags: php, wampserver, opencart-module, opencart-3

Hopefully a simple question.

Running WAMP for module development, what folder permissions should I set?
I've only ever run OpenCart on my Linux servers.

OpenCart version: 3.0.2.0

The issue I'm having when I update my module it isn't updating `\system\storage\cache`, so my front end never refreshes. It took my while to workout I have to delete my cache folder every time I upload a new version, as everything else was working fine.

`\system\storage\modification` is updating correctly. Database entries are updating correctly. It is just my cache folder won't update if the file is already there.

Or am I completely wrong and it's a WAMP config issue?
I've always used WAMP for development and never had an issue modifying files from PHP with the default WAMP installation.

Comment: it is not with the cash i think. it is because your browser is loading old css. try cntrl+F5

Comment: No, because when I delete the files it works, even without forced refresh. But yes I ctrl+F5 by default when I'm coding.

Comment: TBH, I should be running it an Ubuntu virtual machine to know it's compatible. But sometimes it's just easier to run netbeans + wamp.

Comment: check the permission of that folder.

Comment: @Abhinav of course I have done that, "Authenticated Users", "SYSTEM", "Administrators", "Users" all have Full Control. Since originally posting I've found OpenCart can create cache files fine, but once they are created they won't be updated, even after installing paid modules I know work.